# Macros disappearing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet stored in a central server at work with several macros in it. When I click on Developer-->Macros, the list of macros has disappeared, and the "create" button remains greyed out even when I type in a new macro name. The macros still appear in the "Module" list but clicking on them brings up a blank window.

However, when I make a copy of the file, paste it to my desktop, and rename it, the macros reappear.

In a final bizarre twist, when I then copy and paste that newly renamed file back to the work server, the macros disappear all over again.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on? My usual bag of tricks has failed me and I am close to restoring the file to a previous date.

Comment: Talk to your IT department. It sounds like they are against macros (which can be a vector for viruses).

Comment: Ok, thanks John. I thought that might be the case.